# can I get log into an iPad without using security code?

Tags: ipad

I would like to know if there is a way to use someone's iPad without having to type in the security code.

Answer (score 2):

No. The security code prevents use unless you can find a way to crash the security or hack into the device. I know of no vulnerabilities for iPad running the latest iOS 6, but clearly no one can know all the loopholes and there might be a way to bypass things that it still secret.